# Change numeric format, wrong format in dataset

Tags: r, formatting, dataset

I received a dataset to analyze, the first rows are:

```
day;lang;nil;longitude;latitude
0;it;5;918.926.528;4.545.545.373
0;ar;28;92.235.078;4.545.206.021
0;es;65;91.225.254;45.497.917
0;it;21;921.481.788;4.547.046.575
0;it;50;915.995;45.450.124
0;ar;28;922.355.903;4.545.202.558
0;ar;28;922.362.504;454.523.043
0;ar;28;922.318.987;4.545.211.746
```

The problem is the following: the columns of longitude and latitude are not well formatted in the sense that, since I know where these data are taken from, Longitude should be "9,..." and Latitude should be "45,...."

As you can see also the number of digits in each record of longitude and latitude is different!

Any idea on how to solve this (possibly in **R**)?

Comment: There are methods in R to work with this data, but it looks like some of the rows are bogus. They may be typos or might be information from the wrong geographic area. I'd suggest you go back to the data provider and ask what is going on.

Comment: I bet this is the effect of opening and saving a csv file in excel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are "stuck" with this data, then this might help:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text="day;lang;nil;longitude;latitude
0;it;5;918.926.528;4.545.545.373
0;ar;28;92.235.078;4.545.206.021
0;es;65;91.225.254;45.497.917
0;it;21;921.481.788;4.547.046.575
0;it;50;915.995;45.450.124
0;ar;28;922.355.903;4.545.202.558
0;ar;28;922.362.504;454.523.043
0;ar;28;922.318.987;4.545.211.746", 
           header=TRUE, sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

cleanup <- function(x, n) {
  x <- gsub("\\.", "", x)
  x <- sub(sprintf("^%s", n), sprintf("%s\\.", n), x)
  as.numeric(x)
}

df %>% 
  mutate(longitude=cleanup(longitude, 9),
         latitude=cleanup(latitude, 45))

##   day lang nil longitude latitude
## 1   0   it   5  9.189265 45.45545
## 2   0   ar  28  9.223508 45.45206
## 3   0   es  65  9.122525 45.49792
## 4   0   it  21  9.214818 45.47047
## 5   0   it  50  9.159950 45.45012
## 6   0   ar  28  9.223559 45.45203
## 7   0   ar  28  9.223625 45.45230
## 8   0   ar  28  9.223190 45.45212
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do using `base` R:

```
sep <- "."

# remove dots from latitude and longitude
dt$latitude <- gsub("\\.","",dt$latitude)
dt$longitude <- gsub("\\.","",dt$longitude)

# insert your sep at your desired position
dt$longitude <- as.numeric(paste0(substring(dt$longitude,1,1), sep, substring(dt$longitude,2)))
dt$latitude <- as.numeric(paste0(substring(dt$latitude,1,2), sep, substring(dt$latitude,3)))

  # day lang nil longitude latitude
# 1   0   it   5  9.189265 45.45545
# 2   0   ar  28  9.223508 45.45206
# 3   0   es  65  9.122525 45.49792
# 4   0   it  21  9.214818 45.47047
# 5   0   it  50  9.159950 45.45012
# 6   0   ar  28  9.223559 45.45203
# 7   0   ar  28  9.223625 45.45230
# 8   0   ar  28  9.223190 45.45212
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "day;lang;nil;longitude;latitude
    0;it;5;918.926.528;4.545.545.373
                  0;ar;28;92.235.078;4.545.206.021
                  0;es;65;91.225.254;45.497.917
                  0;it;21;921.481.788;4.547.046.575
                  0;it;50;915.995;45.450.124
                  0;ar;28;922.355.903;4.545.202.558
                  0;ar;28;922.362.504;454.523.043
                  0;ar;28;922.318.987;4.545.211.746", header=T,sep=";")
```